# Mysql and php - compare them and bring back one out of the two values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Category      Make    
BUS           hiace
Car           honda
bus           hiace
```

Expected Result:
bus (hiace) - in the drop down list
car (honda) - in a different drop down list

```
 <SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
 function setup(ans) {
 lit = ''
 if (ans == 'bus') {
  <?php 
 $result = mysql_query("select Category from auto
group by Make"); ?>

lit = lit+ '<select name="q4" ONCHANGE="alert(document.quest.q4.value)" style="width:130px; background-color:#FFCC33; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;" >'
lit = lit+ '<option>MAKE</option>'
 <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
$make = $row['Make'];
//print $make;
?>
var make = "<?php echo $make; ?>"
lit = lit+ '<option>'+make+'</option>'

  <?php }?>
lit = lit+ '</select>'
}
 </script>
```

Comment: you want to get the records with lesser ID value when there are duplicates?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Describing what you want in words to ensure we know what you're actually wanting would help. Also, posting the code that you have tried is another thing that you should be doing, we're not here to write code for you but to help with the issues you have encountered

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
where ID IN (select MIN(ID) 
                FROM table 
                GROUP BY Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

For a random ID of the ones matching, try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY Name;
```

or if you want the maximum ID with the same name

```
SELECT MAX(ID),Name FROM table_name GROUP BY name;
```

This naturally works with MIN() too if you want the first ID.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, I actually tested it first, easy to get it wrong if you're just typing an answer from memory :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id,name FROM tbl_names GROUP BY name ORDER BY id ASC ?

Comment: this will throw error.. while grouping you can only have grouped columns and aggregate functions in SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(ID), Name
from tablename
group by Name
```